# Url rewriting in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url-rewriting

Do you know if it's possible to get an url rewrited using GAE and Python in a way that it appears different in also the domain part?

So, for example,

www.aaa.appspot.com to www.bbb.com ??

Answer (score 4):

This is not [Url rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine), it's [custom domains which are supported on GAE](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have requests for .app-id.appspot.com handled differently to .app-id.appspot.com you can use webapp2's DomainRoute. The same would apply to or example.com vs example2.com if you had two custom domains pointing to your app.

See: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html#domain-and-subdomain-routing

That way you can have one AppEngine app that handles requests for both example.com and example2.com (or just handles redirects from example1.com to example2.com).